# Grafana - create table with column values with Prometheus (dynamic) property/label data

Tags: grafana

When I have a Prometheus query resulting in:

```
my_metric{instance="instance1",job="job",prop_1="ok",prop_2="cancel"} 1
my_metric{instance="instance2",job="job",prop_1="error",prop_2="ok"} 1
```

How can I create a Grafana table showing:

```
timestamp | instance1 | ok    | cancel
timestamp | instance2 | error | ok
```

So a Prometheus metric property is mapped to Grafana table column.

**OPEN QUESTION**: Is it possible to change the value of a tag dynamically? So the 3rd and 4th label (or property) values change over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**QUESTION 1:** The first part of the question is simple: Formatting the prometheus labels/properties in a table is easy. The answer you can find in [this description](https://grafana.com/blog/2017/05/12/grafana-4.3-beta-release/).

[image]

How? Just select the 'table' format as shown in the second red box.

[image]

**QUESTION 2**: any idea?

Comment: Answering "Question 2: Is it possible to change the value of a tag dynamically? So the 3rd and 4th label (or property) values change over time" - Switching "Instant" selector (near the Format: Table) helped me.