# Grafana table from Prometheus metric with key-value labels

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have a `metadata` metric in Prometheus that looks like this

```
# HELP metadata Process metadata
# TYPE metadata counter
metadata{hostname="server-a",key="version",value="v1.1.0"} 1
metadata{hostname="server-a",key="feature1",value="true"} 1
metadata{hostname="server-a",key="feature2",value="false"} 1
metadata{hostname="server-b",key="version",value="v1.0.0"} 1
metadata{hostname="server-b",key="feature1",value="false"} 1
```

where the `key` label has the name of the field and the `value` label has a string value. We don't care about the value of the metric, but it'll always be 1.

Is it possible to have Grafana format this as a table? i.e. like this

| Hostname | version | feature1 | feature2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| server-a | v1.1.0 | true | false |
| server-b | v1.0.0 | false |  |

If I have a separate query (with Table format) for each possible `key` then I'm able to make it look like that with two transformations: an `Outer join` by hostname, then a `Organize fields` to remove the excess fields.

However, I'd like to do that without a separate query for each `key`, or even hardcoding `key` if possible. But despite all my fiddling with transforms I can't figure out how. There's also a couple of questions here that ask about similar things, but none of them do exactly what I'm looking for:

- [Table-like visualization with label values as row values and column names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66010367/6936976) which uses the actual metric value for the column values
- [Grafana - create table with column values with Prometheus (dynamic) property/label data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58969018/6936976) has each instance as a single metric with the right labels, instead of spread out over a number of metrics

And a few things that don't work

- A single query for `metadata{}` in table format has a column for the key and a column for the value, rather than column with the name of the key
- Closest I've gotten is with a Time series query then a `Label to fields` transformation, which has a column of 1s whose name is the value of `key`.

So is what I want even possible in Grafana?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new **Grouping to Matrix** transform introduced by [this PR](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/28739) in Grafana v8.5.0, this is now possible!

- Set the Prometheus query to have **Format: Table** and **Type: Instant**.
- Add a **Grouping to Matrix** Transform, with:

  - Column: `key` ("I want a different column for each `key`")
  - Row: `hostname` ("I want a different row for each `hostname`")
  - Value: `value` ("The cell should take the value from `value`")
  - Empty Value: both Null or Empty will produce the correct output
- Add a **Rename by regex** Transform.

  - Match: `(.*)\\.*`
  - Replace: `$1`

  The Grouping to Matrix transform produces a column with name like `<row>\<column>` (e.g. `hostname/\key`), and this fixes that to be just the row name (e.g. `hostname`)
- Finally, set the Visualisation (top right) to **Table**.

Answer (score 1):

Need to select in Options -> Format -> Table

[image]

Comment: This only gives a list of key-value pairs, not a table in the format the question asks.

Answer (score 1):

I've written down [a tiny note](https://medium.com/@moon1706/grafana-label-values-table-fd69535505a0) regarding this problem. From my side, I can suggest using basic transformations:

1. **Organize fields**: remove the *timestamp* column;
2. **Rename by regex**: convert strings on labels to a JSON object like
   `["server-a", "v1.1.0"]`;
3. **Reduce**: move column name to value; *Calculation* can be *Max*;
4. **Organize field**: delete the *Max* column;
5. **Extract fields**: convert the JSON object to a list of columns;
6. **Organize fields**: hide and rename required columns.

All figures are presented in the story. That's not so quick approach, but it works.